# understanding this regular expressions

Tags: javascript

```
    var keys = {};
    source.replace(
            /([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/g,
            function(full, key, value) {
                keys[key] =
                        (keys[key] ? keys[key] + "," : "") + value;
                return "";
            }
    );
    var result = [];
    for (var key in keys) {
        result.push(key + "=" + keys[key]);
    }
    return result.join("&");
    }
    alert(compress("foo=1&foo=2&blah=a&blah=b&foo=3"));
```

i still confuse with this   /([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/g  , the + and * use for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+` and `*` are called quantifiers. They determine how many times can a subset match (the set of characters immediately preceding them usually grouped with `[]` or `()` to which the quantifiers apply) repeat.

```
/     start of regex

 (    group 1 starts
   [^ anything that does not match
   =& equals or ampersand
   ]+ one or more of above
 )    group 1 ends

   =  followed by equals sign followed by

 (    group 2 starts
   [^ anything that does not match
   =& ampersand
   ]* zero or more of above
 )    group 2 ends

/     end of regex
```

Comment: i just dont understand why match foo=1 , it got no &

Comment: The `^` character means NOT. So, `[^=&]` means NOT = and NOT &. Hence, `foo=1` matches. The `=` in the middle matches because of the `=` in the middle of the regex as shown in my answer.

Comment: aw, i got it ,in group 1 ,it do not match any string start with = and &

Comment: Yes. To be more precise it matches one or more `+` of any characters except = and &.

Comment: var str = "foo=1&foo=2&blah=a&blah=b&foo=3";
  document.write(str.match(/([^=&]?)=([^&]*)/g)); why i got o=1,o=2,h=a,h=b,o=3  not f=1,f=2,b=a,b=b,f=3

Comment: @joesmith, it's because the the quantifier you used. `?` means zero or one. Hence it could match only a single character - the last one of all the keys. If you change it to `+` which means one or more you'd get `["foo=1", "foo=2", "blah=a", "blah=b", "foo=3"]` as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The ^ means NOT these, the + means one or more characters matching, the () are groups. And the * is any ammount of matches (0+).

http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

So by looking at it, I'm guesing its replacing anything thats NOT =&=& or &=& or ==, which is wierd.